# innerHTML not updating for some Pre tags

Tags: c#, razor

I've got some serialized JSON data that I need to prettify. So basically I want to display

`{"AuthorizationId":123245,"AuthorizationIdSpecified":true,"ClientAuthorizationId":null,"Date":"2016-12-07T15:22:29+00:00","Message":"","PersonId":"345543654645","Status":0}`

as

```
{
  "AuthorizationId": 123245,
  "AuthorizationIdSpecified": true,
  "ClientAuthorizationId": null,
  "Date": "2016-12-07T15:22:29+00:00",
  "Message": "",
  "PersonId": "345543654645",
  "Status": 0
}
```

hiddenData_* is a hidden span where the JSON originally gets rendered. response-container_* is a pre tag to display structured JSON. There is a Razor loop iterating through the model.

The script is

```js
  var x = document.getElementById("hiddenData_@Model[i].TriggerTime.Ticks").innerHTML;
  var y = JSON.parse(x);
  var z = JSON.stringify(y, null, 2);
  document.getElementById("response-container_@Model[i].TriggerTime.Ticks").innerHTML = z;
```

The problem is that innerHTML of the pre tag is getting updated but are not getting rendered in the DOM. Weird thing is it works for some JSON data but not for others.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What JSON does it work for, what doesn't it work for? If it is consistent, then there is probably an invalid character.

Comment: `var prettyJson = JObject.Parse(json).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);`

Answer (score 0):

As you are putting stringified JSON inside a Pre tag, I believe you could try innerText rather than innerHtml (as you are not adding descendants, but pre-formatted text)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a simpler way to do it using Razor. Thanks for the suggestions.

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Model[i].SerializedEventData), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);`